# H2 - Table not found after ALTER table - leftover "_COPY_" table

Tags: h2

I have an application that uses H2 v1.4.199, with versioning provided by Flyway.

For roughly 25% of the users, this migration ends up in an unusual state.

The migration is performing a number ALTER TABLE commands (typically dropping columns) on one database (lets call the table "fruits").

```
2021-01-25 14:57:04,226 ERROR main h2database - mydatabase:database opening mydatabase
org.h2.message.DbException: Table "FRUITS" not found [42102-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.tryUpdate(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:108)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.update(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:78)
    at org.h2.engine.MetaRecord.execute(MetaRecord.java:60)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:842)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:319)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:313)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:69)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:201)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:178)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:161)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:31)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:336)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:169)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:148)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    ... more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "FRUITS" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.FRUITS ADD CONSTRAINT PUBLIC.CONSTRAINT_23 PRIMARY KEY(ID) INDEX PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_23 [42102-199]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:451)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:427)
    ... 80 more
```

The "fruits" table has a constraint, but they end up without the "fruits" table that acts on and ends up stuck - and you can't even connect to the database.
Looking through the debug logs, I can see the following:

```
2021-02-02 10:11:18 lock: 1 exclusive write lock requesting for FRUITS_COPY_4_3 
2021-02-02 10:11:18 lock: 1 exclusive write lock added for FRUITS_COPY_4_3
```

Looking through the H2 source code, I can see that a temporary table is created with the suffix of "*COPY*", so I'm assuming the existing table is dropped but somehow the temporary table is persisted with the new name,, which means the existing table name is no longer being used.

Unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce this so it's difficult to provide any further information.